# Prove that if $a\mid(2b^2+5c^2)$, then $a\nmid(3b^2-2c^2)$ or $a\le{19c^2}$.

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

Prove that if $a\mid(2b^2+5c^2)$, then $a\nmid(3b^2-2c^2)$ or $a\le{19c^2}$.

I have proved that $a\le{19c^2}$ however I'm not sure how to prove that $a\nmid(3b^2-2c^2)$.

How should I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: $a=1$ is a counterexample...

Comment: You're trying to show $A$ implies ($B$ **or** $C$), not ($B$ **and** $C$).

Answer (score 1):

Either you have $a\not|(3b^2-2c^2)$ in which case you are immediately done, or $a|(3b^2-2c^2)$, in which case $a$ divides
$$
\Big[3\times(2b^2+5c^2)-2\times(3b^2-2c^2)\Big]=19c^2
$$
so in particular $a\leq 19c^2$.